# How to save each sheet of a workbook as a separate file

Tags: excel, vba

Whenever I try to run code that I found online that apparently do this I get a error message.

Run-time error '-2147418113 (8000ffff)'
Automation error
Catastrophic failure

I've tried some modifications but I cant make it work, I've attached the unedited code I've been trying to make work.
Any help would be greatly appriciated.

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

    SaveToDirectory = "C:\Users\Name\OneDrive\Documents\test"

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know if this causing the catastophic failure, but you are missing a path separator (Backslash) between the path and the filename. Also, if your worksheet contains characters that are not allowed in a file name, the code will fail, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1976007/7599798

Comment: Does the Worksheet Name contain Characters that are Forbidden in Filenames, such as `\​`, `/`, `:`, `*`, `?`, `"`, `<`, `>`, or `|`?

Comment: Did you change `C:\Users\Name` into your actual name (or at least, an existing path)?